# RecordType object is not listed as a parent of Account object

Tags: soap-api

With the data model from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_recordtype.htm), the RecordType's child relationships are not listed when trying to retrieve the information from [ChildRelationship](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm). 
Isn't there a way to retrieve the data model and it's relationship using the APIs? All I could see is that the relationships of the entire data model is the following:

```
RecordType  Id  Campaign    CampaignMemberRecordTypeId
RecordType  Id  ContentWorkspace    DefaultRecordTypeId
RecordType  Id  RecentlyViewed  RecordTypeId
RecordType  Id  RecordTypeLocalization  ParentId
```

DescribesObjectResult call of the objects do have "RecordTypeId" field which is marked as a reference but there isn't a way to point that "RecordTypeId" field points to RecordType. Should this reference (to indicate the reference to RecordType) always be hardcoded in applications on such fields? I could see that the potential issue on restore where a custom object that has a record type reference is left out and is not validated if the record type is missing.

Comment: `System.debug(Account.RecordTypeId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo());` does yield `RecordType` for me - am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @DavidReed `for(childrelationship rel: sobjecttype.recordtype.getchildrelationships()) {
    system.debug(rel.getchildsobject()+' '+rel.getfield());
}` -- for some reason it doesn't work in reverse, but other object types do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a glitch on the describe API; I found that Account also doesn't show on my org in Apex code. Instead, you'll want to call describeSObjects and examine each object to determine if it has a record type field or not. Or, alternatively, query the RecordType table directly and get all of the SObjectType values from there. The RecordTypeId field only appears if there's at least one value for a given SObjectType in this table.

Comment: "RecordTypeId" can be filtered for standard objects to construct a relationship but how about the custom objects? Are there any gotchas like the ones in the question "CampaignMemberRecordTypeId" can be determined on the "ReferenceTo" property on the field?

Comment: @dmachop I don't think there's any special rules for custom objects, it should always be RecordTypeId. But in any case, the ReferenceTo property would always point to a RecordType, so that would be the safest detection technique.